# I need to save the results of my for loop into a dataframe

Tags: r, rbind

So, I have a for loop in which I am looping through a dataframe of numbers.
My requirement is to extract all those pairs of (rowid,columnid) of the values in the dataframe that are more than 1.

I tried using rbind but I get an error about unmatched dimensions.
And when I use rbind twice for row and column, it seems to be pasting/appending the same rowid througout. It's getting overwritten at some point, but I cant figure out where.

```
for loop through nrow of matt {
rowsneeded <- which(matt[i, ] >1)
  if (length(rowsneeded ) > 0) {
    resultsdf<-rbind(resultsdf, c(i, rownames(matt[i, findrows, drop = FALSE])))
   resultsdf<-rbind(resultsdf, c(i, colnames(matt[i, findrows, drop = FALSE])))
}
}
```

What I need is:

```
      cat1 cat2 cat3 
cat1   0    0     2
cat2   0    0     3
cat3   2    3     0
```

At the end of my for loop, I need a list or dataframe object in the following format:
condition being: all values greater than 1
So,

```
(cat1, cat3)
(cat2, cat3)
(cat3, cat2)
```

I can later remove the duplicates from the results may be, but the first step would be to get the results of my for loop into a processable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row/column index where value is greater than 0. Then create a new dataframe to get rownames and column names of the index extracted.

```
mat <- which(matt > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)

data.frame(row = rownames(matt)[mat[, 1]], 
           col = colnames(matt)[mat[, 2]], 
           value = matt[mat])

#   row  col value
#1 cat3 cat1     2
#2 cat3 cat2     3
#3 cat1 cat3     2
#4 cat2 cat3     3
```

**data**

```
matt <- structure(list(cat1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L), cat2 = c(0L, 0L, 3L), cat3 = c(2L, 
3L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3"))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. With structure() , can I create the df dynamically? My results are going to be several hundred such (row,column) pairs that I need to extract. So, the dataframe that I need to create, cant have predefined dimensions..

Comment: @Sup I haven't predefined any dimension. I used `df` here which I think is `matt` in your case.

Comment: Thank you. I do have a question, sorry if its too basic. What is the reason for using which() when looping through every column and row with nested for, seems to give more control? Like, I find myself leaning towards creating a row object and binding to my results dataframe.

Comment: You can defintely do that but R has got many functions designed to specially avoid explicit `for` loops like in this case. You are doing `which(matt[i, ] >1)` for every row but basically if you do `which(matt >1)` you get the same result but for the entire matrix without `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, because with which(matt > 1), I get it columnwise. Meaning, multiple row matches with the first column, then second column etc. I want it to match my first row  across columns. So, for that I should go for which( matt[  ,i ] >1)  which is explicit right?

Comment: I am confused. What is `matt` ? Is it the one you have showed (similar to `df` in my answer) and is the output which I have shown matches with what you are looking for?

Comment: I was confused too, since you're answer uses a different mat :) So, matt is my input 3x3 dataframe and "df" that is from your answer will be the result dataframe with selected values .

Comment: I have one last question. After using which(), can I also extract the exact value of the cell along with rownames and colnames?

Comment: Thanks a mil once again Ronak.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this much easily by `melt`ing a `matrix`

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
matt %>%
    as.matrix %>%
    melt %>% 
    filter(value != 0)
#  Var1 Var2 value
#1 cat3 cat1     2
#2 cat3 cat2     3
#3 cat1 cat3     2
#4 cat2 cat3     3
```

---

Or using `base R` by converting to a `table` object and then wrap with `as.data.frame`

```
subset(as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(matt))), Freq != 0)
```

#### data

```
matt <- structure(list(cat1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L), cat2 = c(0L, 0L, 3L), cat3 = c(2L, 
3L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("cat1", "cat2", 
"cat3"))
```